# How to get data blob in php?

Tags: php, ajax, blob

I use recorder.js and I can't upload to server audio blob.
My javascript function is

```
console.log(blob);
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fname', 'test.wav');
fd.append('data', blob);
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'upload.php',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
  }).done(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

My upload.php is

```
<?php
$size = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
echo $size;
if (isset($_POST["data"])) echo " YES :D";
else echo " NO :((";
```

My console is: 475457 NO :((
Why $_POST["data"] is empty? Help me. Thank you.

Comment: It probably doesn't get put into `$_POST['data']`. Instead, try to `print_r($_POST);` to see what your array looks like.

Comment: Result is
Array
(
    [fname] => test.wav
) data is Why not exist and size is large ?

Comment: Hi mate , stucking with the same issue did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use : "$_FILES"  retrieve